# LaTeX problem with position of large table or large algorithm

Tags: tables, positioning, algorithms, algorithmic

I am using the following packages to submit a paper in International Journal of Communication Systems:

```
\documentclass[12pt,peerreview,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2010}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

However, when I insert a table which has for example more than 5 rows or when I write an algorithm which fill entire of a page, the LaTeX put them at the end of the paper!!!

**One of my table:**

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Parameter's Values of Environment}\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{25mm} p{20mm} p{22mm}}
\hline Parameter &various SUs  & various K
\\ \hline Environment & $500\times500[m]$  & $500\times500[m]$
\\ \hline $|\mathcal{M}|$ &10 &5
\\ \hline $|\mathcal{N}|$ &5-50 &50
\\ \hline $r^{PU}(.)$ &150(meter) & 150(meter)
\\ \hline $r^{SU}(.)$ &100(meter) & 100(meter)
\\ \hline No. Rounds &100& 100
\\ \hline No. Time slots &$3\times |\mathcal{N}|$ &100
\\ \hline No. Iteration &1000& 100
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table5}
\end{table}
```

**My algorithm style:**

```
\begin{algorithm}[tb]
\caption{Distributed SCG-RP Algorithm} \label{algorithm1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
...
some \IF
some \STATE
...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: you specified `[h]` which means not top (no t)  not bottom (no p) and not on a page just containing a float (no p), so latex had very few places it is allowed to place the figure so it could not place it anywhere until flushed out at the end of the document. similarly (but not as bad) the algorithm option only has the effect of banning float page (no p) which makes going to the end more likely

Comment: _especially_ if your algorithm fills a page, using the optional argument to ban it being on a page on its own seems inconsistent

Comment: I have changed the option of [h!] in table to [b], [t], [tb], [p], however, it still locate the table at the end of the paper

Comment: `[htbp]` is usually best but anyway there are many things controlling the positioning impossible to say unless you post an actual example document that shows the problem, perhaps in your document the end of document is the first feasible place. Also floats are kept in order so if one table can not be placed and goes to the end, all following ones will be pushed along to the end with it.

Comment: Page 22 and 23 of the fancyhdr documentation contain an overview of the parameters that influence float placement. I don't know if there is any page like that here on tex.se, but you could look that up.

Comment: And here is a short page with similar info: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/float_hint.html